# Can I remove aeadisrv.exe from windows 7?

Tags: operating-systems

I have notice that aeadisrv.exe running on system background and it keep consuming about 22% of the cpu.

Is it okay to remove it from my pc?

Comment: Not an essential Windows process so, yes it can be disabled. But it's part of the sound card drivers/software. Disabling/removing may have undesirable side effects even if the core system remains unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

The aeadisrv.exe belongs to soundmaxsupremefx application. The main function of aeadisrv is to support the audio sound cards.

You don't need to remove this application.

However, if you still want to remove it, then uninstall it from control panel, find out [detail here](https://www.winosbite.com/aeadisrv-exe/).